# Kinect Manipulate Skeleton Data

Tags: c#, .net, kinect

I have a `Skeleton skeleton` which comes from the `SkeletonFrameReady` event. And I have a function to draw skeletons on the windows,

```
void DrawSkeleton(Skeleton s),
```

which takes the Skeleton as the input and draws 2D image of skeleton to my window.

Now, I want to change, for example, x and y value of the right hand and draw it on the window using the same function, `void DrawSkeleton(Skeleton s)`.

However, when I try to do something like:

```
skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X = 3;
```

It doesn't allow me to do that:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'Microsoft.Kinect.Joint.Position' because it is not a variable.

which is probably because `Position` is not a variable, is a property.

**Question:**

How can I duplicate a `Skeleton` object and change the `Position` values of `Joint`s on that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

You simply make a new Position object and overwrite the Position you like.

```
var movedPosition = new SkeletonPoint
{
    X = (float)(mouseJoint.Position.X - 0.4),
    Y = (float)(mouseJoint.Position.Y - 0.3)
};

var movedJoint = new Joint
{
    Position = movedPosition
};
```

*This is an example from an actual project where we wanted to correct the position of the hand to adjust the mouse without actually modifying the skeleton*